# Statistical significance for spectral analysis in python

Tags: python, scipy, fft, python-3.7

I am doing spectral analysis using `Python 3.7`.

I know there are several ways to use `scipy` in Python ([scipy.signal.welch](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html#scipy.signal.welch), [scipy.signal.periodogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html#scipy.signal.periodogram)..)
And the picture that I made using it is as follows.
[image]

But what I want to do is test this statistical significance. Like Red dotted line in the figure below.
[image]

This picture is not the result of using Python. I want to know how to draw a picture like this through Python. Is there a simple way or tool to do it?

It would be helpful if you could attach a site with an example.

Comment: Do you know functions of these red dotted line ?

Comment: @Tiendung I refer to this site. [link](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/Shea_util/specx_ci.shtml)
It is Ncar Command Language function. However, the link is focused on usage rather than a detailed description of the function.

Comment: For statistical significance you need a distribution of measurements. For example, if you had 100 measurements for which you drew the mean PSD, you could compute a statistical significance or margins of confidence. Unless I missed your intentions, I think that more info is needed.